# Here SDK PositionSimulator - Issue, or surprising behaviour, if the signal is temporarily lost (in the file)

Tags: here-api

I'm using a GPX file which contains one point having the network source, the other points come from the gps satellite source. When playing the file and getting this 'network point', then the OnPositionChanged Listener is not triggered during 20 seconds (it should consider that the signal is still the same), I lose the next points and my app considers that the signal is lost during 20 seconds.

This behaviour comes up when playing the file without navigation, it also comes up when navigating, ...but it doesn't occur when the navigation has been launched and it is stopped. In this case, the position of the points after the network point is got normally without the 20s delay.

HERE Developer Support, could you please investigate?

Comment: Please provide us additional info. Are you using: mSDK for Android or iOS, what is version of HERE mSDK, what kind of type your device.

Comment: Here SDK Version: 3.13.2.86 / Android 9.0 / Samsung Galaxy Tab A 2017

Comment: thanks. Try please new 3.14 version there is fix some delays in PositioningManager. 
Some suggestion: if possible use please only LocationMethod.GPS during navigation and LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK at all other cases. This suggestion works for PositionSimulator too.

Answer (score 0):

Try please new 3.14 version there is fix some delays in PositioningManager. Some suggestion: if possible use please only LocationMethod.GPS during navigation and LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK at all other cases. This suggestion works for PositionSimulator too.

Comment: There is no change with the new 3.14 version. The problem is not very important but may cause some issues elsewhere...